# error: no match for ‘operator=' | struct return type

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following error message:

> dec_main.cpp:202: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘dec_log_used = DEC.dec::decode()
>   wrapper.h:2: note: candidates are: dec_log& dec_log::operator=(const dec_log&)

When I run the following code:

**wrapper.h**

```
typedef struct { int wt_sum; float num_itr; } dec_log;
```

**dec.cpp**

```
include "wrapper.h"  
class dec { 
   public:
   dec_log dec_log_used; 
   dec_log decode(); 
};   
dec_log dec::decode() { 
   dec_log_used.wt_sum = 2;       
   dec_log_used.num_itr = 8;
   return dec_log_used; 
};
```

**dec_main.cpp**

```
#include "wrapper.h"
dec_log dec_log_used;
int main() {
   dec DEC;
   ......
   ......
   dec_log_used = DEC.decode();
};
```

Any suggestions on what needs to be fixed here?

Comment: why the `typedef` instead of simply `struct dec_log{ ... }`

Comment: @user6841131  Members of this class     class dec { 
       dec_log dec_log_used; 
       dec_log decode(); 
    }  are private.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow IMVHO you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, you **don't** 'run the following code' as you say. You just try to compile it, but the compilation fails, so you have no code to run...

Comment: @CiaPan His code is entirely invalid because at least there are absent semicolons after class definitions.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow I added the missing semi colons, sorry cut paste issue.

Comment: You're still missing a semi-colon right after `class dec {...}`, and `dec_log_used.wt_sum` should be `dec_log_used.wt_num`.

Comment: AFAICS `dec` is undefined in `dec_main.cpp`.

Comment: I agree with melpomene. The declaration of `class dec` needs to be moved to `wrapper.h`

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: Either provided code is not complete or error message is not complete. The given code would give your an error for calling private method `decode` and for `dec` class in `main` is not even declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `dec` is undefined in the `dec_main.cpp`. Maybe that's why the compiler produces so strange error in this case.

There is a real practice of separating the class declaration and its definition in C++. To prevent double inclusion [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) is used.

So you should have following files.

**wrapper.h**

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

typedef struct { int wt_sum; float num_itr; } dec_log;

#endif
```

**dec.h**

```
#ifndef DEC_H
#define DEC_H

#include "wrapper.h"

class dec
{ 
public:
   dec_log dec_log_used; 
   dec_log decode(); 
};

#endif
```

**dec.cpp**

```
#include "dec.h"

dec_log dec::decode()
{ 
   dec_log_used.wt_sum = 2;       
   dec_log_used.num_itr = 8;
   return dec_log_used; 
}
```

**dec_main.cpp**

```
#include "dec.h"

dec_log dec_log_used;

int main()
{
   dec DEC;
   dec_log_used = DEC.decode();
}
```

In this code include guard is not neccessary, but take it a habit. You may use `#pragma once` instead, but your compiler seems somehow strange.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, this issue has been resolved & the header file was not updated with the correct dec_log which was producing this error.